# Will an iphone user still receive texts from a non-smart phone user if the iphone user has "send from sms" turned off?

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone se ios 13.  Will an iphone user still receive texts from a non-smart phone user if the iphone user has "send from sms" turned off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did not receive someone’s texts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386686/did-not-receive-someone-s-texts)

Comment: Please don’t ask the same question twice.  Add the missing details by **editing** the original question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, people without iPhones can send you text messages as SMS independent of the state of the “Send as SMS” option (would be difficult to receive any text messages from any non-iPhone user otherwise).  The “Send as SMS” option only controls how *your* phone reacts if you want to send an iMessage to another iPhone user. If iMessages is not available currently, sending such a message will fail unless the option is enabled.